# I want to create a login form but i have a problem with a label

Tags: html, css

I want to create a login form that have a label with a placeholder and when I click to the label to insert text on that label and the placeholder I want to show above the text inserted.

I will give some images for my example i want to copy.
[Images - imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Peb.jpg)

This is one label that I want to make

```css
.capo {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  color: black;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="">
    <label>
 <input class="capo" placeholder="AboveInput"> 

</input>
</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. I recommend looking into CSS animations and pseudo elements

Comment: I have to agree with Zach.
You need to phrase it properly as a problem. Describe what you want (which you have) and then what you attempted to do, and what is going wrong. (and include that problem in the title)

Also if you want the easy way out you can get a elements library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want functionality like floating label input in your input element. You can create a custom input using a `label, id and htmlfor`. That you have to figure out. I will not write the code piece for you.

Or you can directly use any UI library like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/) or material UI, with predefined `HTML attributes & CSS classes`. This can save you some time.